# difference between Java and C++ copy constructor

Tags: java, c++, copy-constructor

I am curious how Java supports copy constructor and how is it different from C++? I would like to understand the Java equivalent of the logic to execute rule of three (copy constructor, destructor, assignment operator) from the compiler side of the story.

Comment: no, java supports only references to classes while c++ supports value & references, so java doesnt support copy ctors, dtors, or assign ops

Comment: @Kal Wrong. Java supports copy constructors just fine, and most Collections classes supply them.

Comment: @chrylis: automatic copy constructors? I don't think so.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Built-in support, no, but the language allows the idiom without any problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java has no specific linguistic support for copy constructors.  Rather you just code the state copying by hand in the constructor; e.g.

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(Person other) {
        this.firstName = other.firstName;
        this.lastName = other.lastName;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

> I would like to understand the Java equivalent of the logic to execute rule of three (copy constructor, destructor, assignment operator) from the compiler side of the story.

The copy constructor is as above.  Is really just a (simple) design pattern.

Java doesn't provide an equivalent to C++ assignment operator loading.  Java supports assignment of primitive types and reference types, but not assignment of objects in the same way that C++ does.  It is unusual for special actions are required when assigning a value in Java.  And in the cases where you need to do this, it is customary to put the logic into a setter method.

Java supports `finalize` methods, that are similar *in some respects* to C++ destructors.  The primary differences are that `finalize` methods are operations on objects not reference variables, and they are typically called a long time after the object's last reference has gone out of scope.

However, you *rarely* need to use `finalize` methods:

- Java is a fully garbage collected language, and the best strategy for memory management is to just let the GC take care of it.
- Other resources are best managed using "try / finally" or "try with resources".

AFAIK, the only *sound* use-case for `finalize` methods is for cleaning up resources that have been lost accidentally; e.g. because someone forgot to "close" them using the recommended mechanisms.

Comment: Copying is normally done for mutable "value" objects -- eg MutableRectangle (if you needed/wanted such a class). It's arguably not really sensible/useful for "identity" objects/ entities such as Person.

Comment: This code snippet is the right idea but would be more revealing if it shoed some deep copy action going on, which is the purpose of the hand-rolled copy constructor.    Strings and the native scalars are too easy.

Comment: @ThomasW - it is a quick example to show how Java works ... not something that is intended to make sense from a domain perspective.  Please focus on what the Answer is trying to say.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti - The purpose of a hand-rolled constructor is to do whatever the designer intends it to do!  There's no fundamental reason to restrict copy constructors to deep copy or shallow copy or full copy or partial copy ...

Comment: @ThomasW - besides, in some applications the names of a `Person` object *may* need to change!

Comment: Well, I gave you a +1 for the answer. But choosing an appropriate _design_ for the domain, is important to illustrate examples correctly. Design is a more subtle area than code, but one frequently gotten wrong -- and arguably more important.

Comment: Please don't change the names of Persons or Customers in my systems/apps by copying & saving duplicates all through the database! You're welcome to duplicate 'Order' or 'Job', though. :)

Comment: Agreed.  I'm just a context junkie, that's all.   And upon reflection I omitted some myself in that comment.

Answer (score 5):

Java only has references to objects. You can't declare inline (on stack or in object) objects.

> copy constructor

Java doesn't have one.  You can write one but this is rarely done.

> , destructor

Java doesn't have one.  It has `finalize()` but this is highly discouraged.

> assignment operator

Java doesn't have one for objects, only references to objects.

Comment: @johnchen902 Sorry, it is finalize() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()